Data sanitation options on INSERT or UPDATE
The answer in this post is pretty much what I did to get my problem:
SQL Server trigger before insert or update depend on value
I have a CUSTOMER table that has multiple triggers attached. One of these is responsible for sanitizing data entered into a specific column on the table...stripping a comma off the end of a customer's NAME.
Each time the sanitizing trigger is fired, it ends up triggering the other triggers on the table, which causes a lot of needless logic and slows the update to a crawl.
I could do this in the Application, but there's many other SQL processes out there that updates data in this table, and it'd miss all of those.
Is there a way to update a table without triggering the other triggers temporarily?
If not, is there some way of doing data sanitation on INSERT/DELETE that doesn't involve a trigger?
Things I tried:
I tried finding a way to run my trigger without hitting others and saw this:
Will one trigger activate another trigger in SQL Server?
There's a setting..Allow Triggers To Fire Others, but that's a global change and could break so much else.
I looked for some variant of CHECK CONSTRAINT to see if it could actually correct data, but it doesn't.
Maybe I could play with the order of the triggers? Not sure it that would actually help, though.
